# Optimise JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, performance

Can someone please help me to find best way to optimise the below code as it is taking a long time when I have thousand of records searching

```
var arr =[
   {
      children:[
         {
            children:[
               {
                  children:[
                     {
                        name:'XYZZZZZ'
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
];

        let list = [];

        //Calculate column list
        arr.forEach((obj0) => {
            if (obj0.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
                if (obj0.children.length > 0) {
                    let objchid1 = obj0.children;
                    objchid1.forEach((obj1) => {
                        if (obj1.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
                            if (obj1.children.length > 0) {
                                let objchid2 = obj1.children;
                                objchid2.forEach((obj2) => {
                                    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
                                        if (obj2.children.length > 0) {
                                            let objchid3 = obj2.children;
                                         objchid3.forEach((obj3) => {
                                            if (obj3.name !== 'james') {
                                    console.log('IN THREEE', obj3.name);
                                                list.push(obj3.name);
                                                }
                                            });

                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

I have tried searching a lot but no luck Thanks in advance.!!!

Comment: I would recommend looking into creating a recursive function

Comment: A recursive function will look a lot cleaner but all the processing steps will still be the same and I doubt will change performance much

Comment: If you are running this multiple times (such as a search tool) should consider storing the results

Comment: @charlietfl Even if it would only make it look better, that is still an optimization of a sort. But the good thing about recursion is that you only check if there is a `children` and doesn't matter if it is 24 deep...recursion will check 24 deep in one line compared to 24 tabbed columns of forEach loops.

Comment: Can the object have a name property at any level?

Comment: Drop the unnecessary `if (obj.children.length > 0) {` conditions

Comment: Are you always searching only for `james`? Then no, there is not really a way of optimising this without starting with a different data structure in the first place.

Comment: @Matt just trying to give OP reasonable expectations. OP did mention that time to run (performance) was an issue

Comment: create a new array of Object to search, so, you need only go throught an unique array and your search goes more quickly. e.g you can have some like [{name:'aaa',index0:0,index1:0,index2:0},{name:'aab',index0:0,index1:0,index2:1}..{name:'rst',index0:10,index1:2,index2:0}..]

Comment: I don't think performance can be noticeably improved here with this data structure. You have to optimize the data to decrease complexity: 1. If the data is sorted, you can use binary search, which is way faster. 2. If you use hash maps, accessing values has constant time. You can also use the tree AND a hash map for fast access. Then you have to update the data structures simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Optimize your data structure. Do not use nested arrays unless you really need to. NoSQL is so popular when it comes to WebDev because reads happen 100.000 times more than writes and saving on bandwidth (for you and the user) is worth more than saving on duplicate data in a database considering how cheap hardware is
2. You can save the elements of the deepest array as object keys (with the nested .name attribute in your case) and the index of the respective position in the array as the object value. This way you can do `myArray[myElementsToIndexObject['elementIamLookingFor']]` iterating only one single time over the nested array (for building `myElementsToIndexObject`)

Answer (score 0):

If the data is from a JSON string, the search can be done during the parsing :

```js
var list = [], json = '[{"child":[{"child":[{"child":[{"name":"XYZZZZZ"}]}]}]}]'

var arr = JSON.parse(json, (key, val) => (key === 'name' && list.push(val), val))

console.log(list)
console.log(arr)
```